# New Class at Eclipse issue

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

Im having an issue with trying to make a new Class in Eclipse.
I am having an existing Application.java and I want to use MySQL statements.
But because I dont want to use them all the time, I was advised to use another class for the connection JDBC-MySQL. The ServerConn.java(my 2nd class) is not compiling due to this errors:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.Connection to Connection

The method createStatement() is undefined for the type Connection
```

The code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ServerConn extends Application{

    public ServerConn()
  {
      Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ) ;
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/promitheas?user=me&password=8888") ;
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have your own class called Connection? if not you may import something else. check  the imports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created your own `Connection` class in the default package, and the Java compiler gets confused. Reason for this is because it interprets it as if you're trying to to assign an object of type `java.sql.Connection` to a variable of your `Connection` type.

Try:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/promitheas?user=root&password=");
```

Alternatively, remove your own `Connection` class, or move it to another package (and don't import it).

Comment: my bad...everything ok

Tried to edit my anwser and say everything ok but you caught me up